# Calculate proportion of specific letters in a file using AWK

Tags: bash, unix, awk

First of all, thank you for helping with my problem. I have a csv file where I have a column that have different letter encoded, as you can see here.

```
ABC
CD
EF
F
D
F
AS
```

I know how to calculate the proportion of F in the column and display the output as follows:

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0;count=0}{count++}{if($1="F")sum+=$1}END {print sum/count}'
0.286
```

But my problem is that I want to do it generally with every single line of the column that have one character so the output will be:

```
F 0.286
D 0.143
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw), thank you.

Comment: Please update yoiur sample input and current output to show what result you expect if you have duplcate single line records, i.e. 2 `F`s. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `if ($1=="F")` to filter out a specific character, store all single letters in an array and iterate over them at the end.

```
awk 'length($0)==1{a[$0]++} END{for(c in a) print c, a[c]/NR}'
```

Arrays in `awk` have no fixed iteration order, so the output might be either

```
F 0.286
D 0.143
```

or

```
D 0.143
F 0.286
```

If you want a fixed order, pipe the result through `sort`.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
awk '
/^.$/{
  count[$0]++
}
END{
  for(key in count){
    print key,count[key]/FNR
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                    ##Starting awk program from here.
/^.$/{                   ##Checking condition if line is having 1 character long.
  count[$0]++            ##Creating count with index of current line and keep increasing count of it with 1 here.
}
END{                     ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(key in count){     ##Traversing through count array here.
    print key,count[key]  ##printing key and printing divide of value of count with FNR.
  }
}
' Input_file             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```